# Javascript code loading issue with IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

The website in question is [cpavalet.com](http://cpavalet.com)

My javascript loads fine on all browsers except ie7 and ie8. For a few hours now I have been trying to debug the issue to no avail.

I am using jQuery and modernizr, and using the supersized library for the full-sized background images.

The weird thing is, sometimes when I load the page it loads correctly, other times the javascript doesn't work on the page. I think it has to do with the order the scripts are loaded. I am using document.ready for my jquery scripts.

Can anyone shed some light as to why it's not working correctly in ie7 and ie8? I am currently using ie8 for testing purposes.

I am using javascript for: image slider on home page, full-size background images, back to top link to slide to the top, and form validation.

Thanks!

Corey

Comment: Using the developer tools in ie9, I switched to ie7 and ie8 browser modes and it worked just fine with no errors.  What errors are you getting?  What doesn't work?

Comment: Works for me as well. However, you state that you're using modernizr, (I see that it's loading, but you never make use of it.)

Comment: I am using modernizr to add different css styles based off of of browser features. As far as the error, I don't see an error either. If you use the developer tools in ie9, switch the document mode to ie7 or ie8. Sometimes you have to refresh the page a couple of times for the error. Bascially, no javascript works. The background doesn't load, the back to top button breaks, and the form's js doesn't work.

Comment: You comment "Basically, no javascript works," sounds a bit like an exception is being thrown and quietly ignored. Have you used the developer tools debugger to check for that possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess as to why it wasn't loading correctly was partly correct. I thought that it was because of the order I had my scripts being run on the page.

The answer is that I was using the **defer** attribute when loading my scripts. When I removed the **defer** attributes, the scripts started working correctly again.